# How to run zend and codeigniter on same domain and in different folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, zend-framework

I am working on a website whose frontend is in zend framework and admin section is in codeigniter. Both the sections were build on separate domains but now I need to configure it so that both admin and frontend works.

This is the structure right now.

```
/public_html

/admin
/application
/library
/public
```

In this under admin section is in codeignitor rest folders are of frontend which is in zend.

What I need is .htaccess rewrite rule so that both the admin and frontend works.

Right now this is what I tried.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/.*$
    RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

I applied the condition so that if there is no admin folder then only it will point to public folder for the frontend which is in zend.

It is working only for /admin folder but if there comes any other action after /admin like /admin/dashboard then it again go through that rewrite condition and points to /public folder which is of zend and then I get the error of page not found.

Can anyone give me the proper .htaccess rewrite condition please?

Answer (score 0):

I have the following setup

public_html
- project-folder
- another-folder

And configured by .htaccess as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!project-folder/).*)$ project-folder/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!another-folder/).*)$ another-folder/$1 [NC,L]
```

Change your .htaccess code as needed.

inside my project-folder contains the whole CodeIgniter project (application, assets, index.php, etc). While another-folder is the root folder of my other project.

Hope this can help.